# BPEL correlation: multiple instances created for same correlation ID

Tags: xml, tomcat6, bpel, apache-ode

I'm working on a BPEL process in Apache ODE with Tomcat 6.

My start activity looks like this:

```
<receive name="Start" partnerLink="myrole" operation="StartProcess"
    variable="StartProcessRequest" createInstance="yes">
    <correlations>
        <correlation initiate="yes" set="CorrID" />
    </correlations>
</receive>
```

The CorrID is an element on the message StartProcessRequest, which is used to fill the variable with the same name.

Everything works great, except for one pretty alarming problem: when an instance already exists for a given CorrID, it doesn't reject it, but creates an extra instance for the same CorrID.

I would expect the ODE engine to raise a fault automatically, but apparantly, some extra work is needed. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You said that the CorrID is an element on the input message.

It seems that this value isnt unique within system users and/or client.

You'll need to create an unique value, engine won't reject it automatically.